# How to Change Agregated Data to Continuous

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I would like to change the following two graphs in this link [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZxQWGq8m4m69bm2lLO1qufNJqwUFfrqDWvHVR_tizk4/edit?usp=sharing)

## Problem 1

Under the chemistry and physics tab I have a graph like this:
[image]

Which is an agregate data set, but as you can tell the x-axis is not continuous nor is it chronological. How do I fix this?

## Problem 2

On the dasboard tab I have this graph:
[image: g]
As well as having the same problem as the other graph, I would like to separate this one into physics and chemistry but I am unsure of how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem 1, you can add another tab then sort the data with `=SORT`

[here's an old answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54538509/sorting-data-on-google-sheets-chart)

I update [your sheet with a "data" tab](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZxQWGq8m4m69bm2lLO1qufNJqwUFfrqDWvHVR_tizk4/edit?usp=sharing).

With some combination of arrays you can regroup data to sort them and make some clean graphs.

I select the data i need between brackets to create an array `{Chemistry!B3:C23;Chemistry!D3:E23}`

Then i sort it by date here the column (`1`) and ask for an ascendant behavior `TRUE`

I now have all the data `SORT({Chemistry!B3:C23;Chemistry!D3:E23},1,TRUE)`

Same job for the physics' data.

To separate physics and chemistry on the same graph the easy way is to create an array with the date in common then add column physic and column chemistry side by side. Then you just retrieve data with a filter : `FILTER($A$2:$B100,$A$2:$A100=E3)`

I add an extra layer by creating another set of data to capture only workdays.

You can check the Dashboard tab and hide the data tab when you're done.